# How to insert the records in a table with where clause

Tags: oracle10g

How to insert the records in a table with where clause

I want to insert the values in a column of a same table, by the reference of another column values in same table by using where clause.

Answer (score 4):

```
Insert into Table_1 (col_a, col_b) 
select val_1, val_2 from dual
where 0 = (select count(*) from Table_1 where col_a = val_1);
```

This would prevent inserting the value twice.

Comment: I was looking for a way to have where  clause in the insert. Excellent trick!

Answer (score 0):

1. To copy rows of the same table and specifying value for specific column:

   INSERT INTO payment_tbl (col1, col2, col3)
   SELECT col1, col2, 'i_changed_value_of_col3' FROM payment_tbl WHERE item_description = 'vegetables'
2. To duplicate rows:

   INSERT INTO payment_tbl
   SELECT * FROM payment_tbl WHERE item_description = 'vegetables'